# Make RotateAnimation Restart smooth

Tags: android, animation, rotation, restart, angle

I have been working on `RotateAnimation` was able to make it work. The only problem that I face right now is that the `RESTART` of the `Animation` is not smooth. I am rotating a `View` and then taking the current angle of the `View` by overriding the following method,

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
    float degrees = fromDegrees + ((toDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);                               
}
```

to plot the following graph,

[image: Image Representation]

As you can see that the `REVERSE`(TOP Curve) is smooth and is proper, but when the `Animation` restarts it stops first and then restarts (BOTTOM Curve).

I would want to make the bottom it like the curves on the top. A perfect sine wave.

Any ideas on how to make the restart just like reverse i.e without the pause, so that the `Animation` and the Graph is smooth.